# Laser beam quality problem: The laser beam showed very different during using the CCD testing directly or using the M2 measurment machine

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, fiber-optics

Recently, we encountered a problem with the laser beam profile characterization, where two testing methods showed two distinct results of the beam profile of the same laser system.

When we used a CCD Beam Profiler to test the beam profile characterization of a 532nm laser frequency, which is double the fundamental laser of 1064nm, the beam was almost looked like the LP01 mode, which is shown in the attachment，and we can promise that the beam profile characterization we tested was around the beam waist of the laser system we built.
the beam profile of the “far~2m/532nm” is kind of like a hexagon. which is a little different with the 1064nm laser

[image]

[image]

But here's the puzzling thing，when I used the M2 testing machine to test the beam quality of our laser system，the result report showed that there  seems to be LP11 mode at the waist position, and M2 was close to 1.72，which is shown below:

[image]

[image]

FYI,the beam quality of 1064nm laser is shown below:

[image]

[image]

so my question is: Is there something wrong during our testing or what reasons led to the two different results. How to explain it？

Comment: This is not an engineering question it's a question about experimental design. It should not be closed as _engineering_.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your actual setup as it is known that you may have some SHG conversion inefficiencies that lead to higher order modes being excited.

You can find some information about high-order excitation due to phase mismatch in this 2020 paper from Bell: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331513160_Intracavity_second_harmonic_generation_for_higher-order_laser_modes

That being said: Can you complement your post with which setup you are using (if you don't want to share which laser, you can at least which crystal you are using and which optics you are using).

It is possible that maybe by adjusting the position of the optics to the SHG crystal you are using may increase the phase matching. I would, for example: 1) Adjust the crystal position to a different region (you may have some defects in the zone where the pump laser is interacting with the crystal). Additionally check the focus and collimation optics of your crystal (if present) as they may have small defects that cause your conversion to be inefficient.

Regarding the different readings: It is possible that, since you are already measuring relatively far from the beam waist (I see a difference of roughly 400mm between the near and beam waist position) you are not really measuring the higher order modes excited but already a dominant LP10 mode. I cannot say with extreme certainty as it depends on your setup.

Comment: thanks for u answer,the crystal LBO and a F50mm Lens were used in our extracavity frequency doubling experiment(with NCPM).the beam diameter of the 1064nm fiber laser is ~4mm；    and we has already adjusted the position of the all optics element to

Comment: Thanks for sharing that information. I think that it is possible that you may be exciting a higher order mode that looks "fine" in the far field (although weirdly shaped e.g. the hexagon that you are seeing) but when measured with the $M^2$ tool you see the actual shape of the beam. Here you can see an experiment done with fibers that may be a useful reference. https://opg.optica.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-15-23-15402&id=144704

Comment: thanks again,the reference you just shared I happened to read it recently, too,  you are so knowledgeable to find out the crux of my problem immediately！on the other hand and is it possible that  the different beam profiles are caused by “diffraction" after focusing through a lens in the M2 testing machine.  I means that if do not focus with some short-focus objective this beam （~4mm waist diameter of 532nm）in air，ones can not  see the double core laser beam (LP11 mode)? Is it Possible？

Comment: In addition，as you say，after use another long-Focus Lens like F-100mm，the M2 quality seems to be optimized ,and do not show the evident LP11 mode like. so this must be some phase mismatching during the previous experiment . and so exciting   
a HOM.

Comment: Yes, I also agree that there is a strong possibility that there is a misalignment close to the SHG crystal. I suggest to do a beam path walk and try to optimize the position of the beam closer to the SHG and double-check with both instruments (but mostly focus on the M2 as it seems to give a very accurate result) until you get a more desirable outcome.